# How to grep cloud functions in a multiline format separated by comma?

Tags: node.js, typescript, shell, google-cloud-functions, multiline

I have been trying to fetch the cloud functions using grep/awk/sed however the current command is not fetching the cloud functions listed in a multiline format.

This is the current command that is being passed as a variable during runtime:

**deploy.sh**

```
functions_list=$(grep 'export' src/index.ts | awk -F '[}{]' '{print $2}' | sed 's/^ *//; s/ *\$//; /^\$/d' | grep -v somefunction || echo '')
```

**index.ts**

```
export { functionA } from './functions';
export { functionB } from './functions';
export {
    functionC,
    functionD,
    functionE
} from './functions';
export { functionF } from './functions';
export { functionG } from './functions';
```

**Then the output will be like this:**

```
functionA
functionB

functionF
functionG
```

**Anyone who has any idea on how to have the output to be like this instead?**

```
functionA
functionB
functionC
functionD
functionE
functionF
functionG
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See final command:

```
functions_list=$(awk 1 ORS=' ' src/index.ts | sed -e 's/    / /g ; s/;/\n/g' | awk -F '[}{]' '{print $2}' | sed 's/^ *//; s/ *\$//; /^\$/d; s/,  /\n/g' | grep -v somefunction || echo '')
```

**awk** reads/scans input *line by line*; hence skips the **functionC, functionD and functionE** as they do not fall under the provided pattern:

> ```
> '[}{]' '{print $2}'
> ```

I've added awk/sed commands to initially replace new line with whitespaces.

```
awk 1 ORS=' ' src/index.ts | sed -e 's/    / /g ; s/;/\n/g'
```

Then, finally, to replace commas with newline.

```
s/,  /\n/g
```

Comment: Adding more pipes between Awk, `sed`, and `grep` is almost certainly avoidable. See [useless use of `grep`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Comment: This worked perfectly! I had to add a few tweaks to the final command to not include those inside the import {} functions. Thanks much!! :)

Answer (score 0):

The parsing here is very brittle. Without complicating things too much, try switching to Perl, which lets you examine the whole input file in one go.

```
perl -n0777 -e 'while (m/export \{([^{}]+)\}/mg) { $s = $1;
  print "$1\n" while $s =~ m/\b((?!somefunction|otherfunction)\w+)\b/mg }' src/index.ts
```

The first regex loops over the `export { ... }` expressions and pulls out the text between the braces. The second picks out the symbols, skipping any whitespace or punctuation, and prints them.

The negative lookahead illustrates how to exclude `somefunction` or `otherfunction` from matching.